# multi-select with search ability in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I started angularjs two weeks ago. I should make a multi select input with search ability.
What I made has 2 problems that I can't fix.
first when I search for "a" it won't filter correctly to only show "a" but the other work fine
second it has a bug when I select "a" to "d" and then deselect from "a" to "d" the last 2 won't delete and the second time that I do this it get's worse.

- please try to edit my own code if possible because I'm not good at reading other people's code

appreciate any help

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.selectEnable = false;
 $scope.selectedItems = [];

 $scope.openSelect = function () {
  $scope.selectEnable = !$scope.selectEnable;
 };

 $scope.itemChecked = function (data) {

  data.flag = !data.flag;
  var selected = $scope.datas.indexOf(data);
  var x = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(data);
  if ((data.flag == true) && (x == -1)) {
   $scope.selectedItems.push(data.item);
  } else {
   $scope.selectedItems.splice(selected, 1);
  }
 };

 $scope.datas = [
  {
   "item": "a",
   /*"category": "x",*/
   "flag": false
  },
  {
   "item": "b",
   /*"category": "y",*/
   "flag": false
  },
  {
   "item": "c",
   /*"category": "x",*/
   "flag": false
  },
  {
   "item": "d",
   /*"category": "y",*/
   "flag": false
  }
 ];


});
```

```css
ul li {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

#category {
 text-align: center;
 background: #ddd;
}

#listContainer {
 width: 20%;
}

span {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()">
 <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
  <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField">
  <div id="listContainer">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in datas | filter: searchField">
     
     <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="selectedItems">
     {{data.item}}
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>




 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you doing this to learn, or do you need this functionality?  If you just need the functionality, it's already there in angular-ui-select: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: I altready saw that my boss said that I should learn to make sth like that that can access api and has loader and has scroll that load the data when scroll so I'm breaking it to smaller tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

**1-** Change your `itemChecked` function to this

```
$scope.itemChecked = function(data) {
    var selected = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex(function(itm) {
      return itm == data.item
    });
    if (selected == -1) {
      $scope.selectedItems.push(data.item);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(selected, 1);
    }


    };
```

**2-** Add an array for showing data after any filtering. Also add a function which filter your data according to input text:

```
$scope.filter = function() {
    if (!$scope.searchField) {
      $scope.data2Show = angular.copy($scope.data);
    } else {
      $scope.data2Show = [];
      $scope.data.map(function(itm) {
        if (itm.item.indexOf($scope.searchField) != -1) {
          $scope.data2Show.push(itm);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.data2Show = [];
```

Use this array to show items in list:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in data2Show">
```

**3-** Write a function to check if an item is selected or not and use:

```
$scope.isChecked = function (data) {
    var selected = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex(function(itm) {
      return itm == data.item;
    });
    if (selected == -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

And usage in html :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="selectedItems" ng-checked="isChecked(data)">
```

**4-** Change checkbox ngModels from `selectedItems` to `data.flag`

```
ng-model="data.flag"
```

---

Final code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectEnable = false;
  $scope.selectedItems = [];

  $scope.openSelect = function() {
    $scope.selectEnable = !$scope.selectEnable;
  };

  $scope.itemChecked = function(data) {
    var selected = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex(function(itm) {
      return itm == data.item;
    });
    if (selected == -1) {
      $scope.selectedItems.push(data.item);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(selected, 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.filter = function() {
    if (!$scope.searchField) {
      $scope.data2Show = angular.copy($scope.data);
    } else {
      $scope.data2Show = [];
      $scope.data.map(function(itm) {
        if (itm.item.indexOf($scope.searchField) != -1) {
          $scope.data2Show.push(itm);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.isChecked = function(data) {
    var selected = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex(function(itm) {
      return itm == data.item;
    });
    if (selected == -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  $scope.data2Show = [];

  $scope.data = [{
      item: "a",
      /*"category": "x",*/
      flag: false
    },
    {
      item: "b",
      /*"category": "y",*/
      flag: false
    },
    {
      item: "c",
      /*"category": "x",*/
      flag: false
    },
    {
      item: "d",
      /*"category": "y",*/
      flag: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.filter();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#category {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

#listContainer {
  width: 20%;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()">
  <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
    <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
    <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField" ng-change="filter()">
    <div id="listContainer">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data2Show">

          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="data.flag" ng-checked="isChecked(data)"> {{data.item}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There are some prepared directives for multi-selecting. for example this one [Angular-strap selects](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects)

Comment: Did I miss something in answer? @soheilPs

Comment: thank you for your answer saeed, I should throughly read it to understand it completely as I said I'm not good at reading other people codes. either way thank you very much

Comment: khahesh mikonam, chiz pichideE estefade nakardam. soali bud darbare javabe, bepors hminja @soheilPs

Comment: thanks again, I have a question: what is this line function? It's the first time that I saw this kink of function. ==> var selected = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex(function (itm) {
   return itm == data.item;}

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). this method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.@soheilPs

Comment: but it works with this too, is the findIndex() better in any way? it's in es6 too.
  var selected = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(data.item);

Comment: I don't know exactly which one is better. Use `indexOf`. @soheilPs